# Spring - Logback catch logging events

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, logging

I am new to Spring and logging.

My aim is it to create a custom repository containing the data of the Logback loggers `e.g logger.name / logger.level / logger.message`

which will then be mapped to a `MySQL DB`.

The problem is I dont know how to catch the logging events. 
I tried to instantiate LoggingEvent (ILoggingEvent). But this returns me always `"null"`.

I dont want to use the typical `"Spring-logback-way"` because I am creating a custom MySQL-DB with Custom named tables / attributes.

Which Interface/Class i have to use to catch the actual loggingEvent?

Answer (score 0):

step 1: First you to have to include log4j.jar in your project.

```
step 2.Configure JDBCAppender in log4j.properties file as bellow to store 
       logging in database.

log4j.properties:

    # Define the root logger with file appender
    log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, sql

    # Define the file appender
    log4j.appender.sql=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
    log4j.appender.sql.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
    # Set Database Driver
    log4j.appender.sql.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    # Set database user name and password
    log4j.appender.sql.user=root
    log4j.appender.sql.password=password
    # Set the SQL statement to be executed.
    log4j.appender.sql.sql=INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES ('%x', now() 
        ,'%C','%p','%m')
    # Define the xml layout for file appender
    log4j.appender.sql.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

Step 3: Log4jJDBCExample to configure log4j and ites priority level message

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class Log4jJDBCExample
{
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Log4jJDBCExample.class);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");

        log.debug("Sample debug message");
        log.info("Sample info message");
        log.error("Sample error message");
        log.fatal("Sample fatal message");
    }
}


Step 4: Create the table in database and test the application

    Create the database table LOGS, in schema test.

    CREATE TABLE LOGS
    (
        USER_ID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        DATED   DATETIME NOT NULL,
        LOGGER  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        LEVEL   VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        MESSAGE VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL
    );

Explination:

  log4j.appender.sql.sql=INSERT INTO LOGS VALUES ('%x', now() ,'%C','%p','%m')

  Here now()--> inserts currentdate 
          %c--> Class Name
          %p--> Priority (level)
          %m--> Message
```

Result like bellow:
[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I am searching for, just with a Logback + SLF4J implementation!